# Dynamic naming of .update key Firebase

Tags: javascript, firebase-realtime-database

I have a form where I am uploading many images to different locations, grabbing the `downloadURL` and using `ref.update` to store the URL of the image in the correct DB ref.

I'm wondering if it's possible to use a variable in `.update` to be able to change the key dynamically by grabbing the name of the active file input:

```
handleImgUpload() {
  var activeInput = document.activeElement.name;
  // set up storage refs, upload file then...
  imgStorageRef.child(filename).getDownloadURL().then(function(url){
    ref.update( {
      activeInput: url // HERE IS WHERE I WANT THE VALUE STORED IN activeInput
})
```

In this example the `ref` to be updated will get the string 'activeInput' as the key. Is there a way to add the value that was stored in `var activeInput` instead?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you're trying to dynamically set the property of an object. To do so use `[]` notation. So:

```
handleImgUpload() {
  var activeInput = document.activeElement.name;
  // set up storage refs, upload file then...
  imgStorageRef.child(filename).getDownloadURL().then(function(url){
    var updates = {};
    var key = "activeInput";
    updates[activeInput] = url;
    ref.update(updates)
  })
}
```